# To have multiple sites with similar content on the same server but different IPs?

Tags: seo, search-engines

I have 7 different sites on the same dedicated server.

Two major sites have different IPs, and 5 small share the same IP.

About first 2 they have similar content, but not the same.

Basically they have different:

- URLs
- Titles
- Meta Data

But they both have the same niche.

I was thinking about two strategies.

One is to move one of the sites (from 2 first one) on different server or move 5 other sites on different server. But I'm not sure which way is better.

My questions are:

1. Wouldn't be better from SEO stand point, to move those 2 sites on
   different servers?
2. Does it worth it to spend for additional server?
3. Do you know if Google penalize sites for similar content on the same
   server with different IPs?

Answer (score 1):

How will Google know your content is on the same server, especially if they are on different IPs?

It is possible to host hundreds of sites on the same server, and one site across hundreds of servers.

If everything is working for the user, it will be fine for Google.

Comment: So you are saying if I put 10 sites. For example like carmax, yahoo auto, edmunds on the same server, google won't care about it, right?

Comment: No, shared hosting allows lots of sites on the same server, and even the same address.  That is how the internet is supposed to work, the sites, application layer and hardware can all sit on the layer below in any way they are spread out.

Comment: @Eugene - It's only important to make sure your websites are served on a timely basis to the user. Google only indexes content, it doesn't (shouldn't -- I don't know) log the IP of your server and then rate you for it. Often times, we run one site on many servers as @cjk said, but run them on one IP address via a `proxy server`. How many servers does Facebook run on? Two years ago, 60 thousand! (Now?)